# I am getting this error when trying Hibernate Search

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-search

I am having this error:

> org.hibernate.search.query.engine.spi.QueryDescriptor class file for
>   org.hibernate.search.query.engine.spi.QueryDescriptor not found

```
@Transactional
public void indexEvents() throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);
        fullTextSession.createIndexer().startAndWait();
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
@Transactional
public List<Event> searchForEvent(String searchText) throws Exception
{
    try
    {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();

        FullTextSession fullTextSession = Search.getFullTextSession(session);

        QueryBuilder qb = fullTextSession.getSearchFactory()
                .buildQueryBuilder().forEntity(Event.class).get();
        org.apache.lucene.search.Query query = qb
                .keyword().onFields("name", "city")
                .matching(searchText)
                .createQuery();

        org.hibernate.Query hibQuery = fullTextSession.createFullTextQuery(query, Event.class); //<<--Error
        List<Event> results = hibQuery.list();
        return results;
    }
    catch(Exception e)
    {
        throw e;
    }
}
```

I have added Hibernate and Hibernate Search dependencies.

UPDATE:
I have solved this problem. It was due to differences between the versions of dependencies. Thanks for help

Comment: Please post the full stack trace and mention the versions of Hibernate Search and Hibernate ORM you're using.

Comment: I am using Hibernate Search with version: 5.7.1.Final and Hibernate core with 5.2.10 Final. And i am getting only this when i build my project: org.hibernate.search.query.engine.spi.QueryDescriptor class file for org.hibernate.search.query.engine.spi.QueryDescriptor not found

Comment: error formatted as blockquote

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that the hibernate-search-engine jar is not in your build path. Check that you made all the necessary jars available to your compiler. Ideally you should let a dependency management tool (such as Maven or Gradle) do that for you.

Comment: I am using Maven and i have added the dependency for it.